# Define attribute validation message across models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, rails-activerecord

In my Rails 4 application I check for a unique constraint like so:

```
validates :recipient, uniqueness: {
     scope: :user,
     message: 'You already have a Connection with this user'
}
```

Now even though it concerns the `recipient` I want to display the error message on the `recipient.email` field.

Is a way to do this using `validates` syntax.

**Update**: This is on some sort of message thread that one user can only have one with another user. Hence the validation.

Comment: What model if your above code snippet from?

Comment: It's some sort of MessageThread which a user can only have one with another user. I did update my answer.

Comment: Is email an attribute of MessageThread?  How is the email param handled as part of the form?

Comment: Do you have a `RecipientModel`? If so, you would place the validation for email inside such model. Your current validation makes sure that `MessageThread` _has a unique recipient_. I would suggest posting model itself -- class declaration, validations, associations.

Comment: You can do it with custom validation logic, `validate :recipient_uniqueness` or something, where you'll do `recipient.errors.add(:email, msg)`

Answer (score 0):

Not a clean solution, but I believe that it's working. But I am not sure.

```
after_validation do
msg = 'You already have a Connection with this user'
   if errors.messages[:recipient] && errors.messages[:recipient].include? msg 
   errors.messages[:recipient].reject!{ |i| i == msg }
   errors.messages[:recipient][:email] = msg
end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Generally my solution I already have works fine and it would show the validation message, however I don't have a distinct field for `recipient` but a sub-form that contains the `recipient` data.

So like Arthur pointed out I probably have to do this with a custom validator. And I got it working now:

```
validate :unique_recipient

def unique_recipient
  if user.threads.map(&:recipient).map(&:email).include?(recipient.email)
  recipient.errors.add(:email, "You already have a connection with #{recipient.first_name}")
  end
end
```

Now the check is a bit hacky, and I liked the simplicity of my original solution but the nice thing with this approach is that I can also display the users `first_name` in the validation message.